# length=1;index=1 when trying to choose an image from the Downloads-Folder

Tags: android, android-intent

I choose a picture using

```
Intent iBildAuswaehlen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
iBildAuswaehlen.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(iBildAuswaehlen, ACTION_PHOTO_WAEHLEN);
```

and I handle the result with

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ACTION_PHOTO_WAEHLEN) {
            if (data == null) {
                f("Fehler");
                return;
            }
            try {
                pfadPhoto = getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());
            }
            catch (Exception iae)
            {
                t(getString(R.string.fFehler)+iae.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            i("ACTION_PHOTO_WAEHLEN "+pfadPhoto);
        }
    }
}
```

This works well with images that are in certain folders. It does not work with with the "Downloads" area(length=1;index=1) is the error message. It works with photos being taken.

How to make it work with the Downloads folder and all other folders that are not protected and should be readable.

Comment: Always post the full stack trace. Using `file://` to access content is frowned upon and in Android N doesn't even work across applications. Rely on `content://` Uris.

Comment: How do I work with content if I want to use BitmapFactory.decodeFile?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method instead of getRealPathFromURI_API19 for getting right path:

```
 public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    // DocumentProvider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```